# Use NSXMLParser delegate to parse two files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I need to parse two completely different XML data files in the same view controller, so I would like to know if it is possible to change the name of NSXMLPaser delegate methods, just for one instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. And there is no need to do that.
Simply differenciante the parsers by checking the first parameter of delegate methods.
For example :

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
```

The concerned parser is always passed as the first argument.

Another solution is to give the two parsers different delegates, so you always know which parser is concerned.

Comment: What attribute of the parameter should I check to differenciate them ?

Comment: attribute ? sorry don't undetstand, but if you got the two parser as ivars of the view controller, a simple `parser == myFirstParser` would tell you if the parser in question is `myFirstParser` or not