# How to parse 2 URL's using NSXMLParser in the same file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsxmlparser

how to parse 2 URL's using NSXMLParser in the same file? I have tried it like this:

```
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:url1];
[self parseXMLFileAtURL:url2];

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{    
    //here both url's returns the same data (element names are same), so how will I differentiate data between first URL & second URL.

    if(url1 data) { 
        //do something
    }
    if(url2 data) { 
        //do something
    }
}
```

so help me to find a way to differentiate.

Comment: I don't know why you want this but I'd declared two separate class for parsing. So I can debug it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter called `parser` **is** the current parser instance used.
This is the way to know which file you are currently parsing.

Alloc/init two separate instances of `NSXMLParser`, and start parsing your two files with.
Assuming they are *ivar* a simple `==` test would tell you which one is used.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8755648/971401) is a link to similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. It's unnecessary. I would have 2 separate NSXMLParserDelegate handling each one. Or i would modify your current class to handle one file at a time, and have 2 instances of it.

You could create a separate delegate class within that class if that's what you like.

eg:

```
@implementation YourCurrentClass

@end

@interface ParserDelegate : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> 
@end

@implementation ParserDelegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:    (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{    
}

@end
```

Use multiple ParserDelegate instances to be the delegates of the parsing. Then have some other code that checks them for the result after they are finished processing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can firstly add your URL objects to an array and later control by the elements of array instead of URL1 & URL2. You can try this:

```
 NSString *obj;
    NSMutableArray *urlArray;
    [urlArray addObject:url1];
    [urlArray addObject:url2];
```

in your parser method:

```
 int i=[[urlArray objectAtIndex:obj] intValue];

switch(i){

case 0:
     // we have url1 here
     //do something with it
      break;
case 1:
     // we have url2 here
     //do something...
      break

}
```

i hope this point of view helps..

Comment: I had said that i'm not sure but the solving is something like this

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 separate objects of NSXMLParser and assign tags and in delegate function check there tag and assign value according to tags.

Comment: we can not assign tags to NSXMLParser instance.